# Integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha + ix} + \frac{1}{\alpha - ix}\right)^2 \, dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm having trouble integrating

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha + ix} + \frac{1}{\alpha - ix}\right)^2 \, dx$$

where $\alpha$ is a real number and $i = \sqrt{-1}$. I'm guessing that I would have to integrate it using methods on complex analysis wherein I would use a semicircle contour enclosing a pole ($x = i\alpha$ for example) so that I could apply the residue theorem. But is there any other way to evaluate this integral (like an ingenious substitution or differentiating under the integral sign)?

Comment: Is the integrand really typed correctly? Should this be, e.g., $\frac{1}{a - ix} + \frac{1}{a + ix}$?

Comment: @Travis Good call, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Have you tried combining the fractions?

Comment: @user170231 Yes, you'd get $\left(\frac{2 \alpha}{\alpha^2 + x^2}\right)^2$ which is another integral that's hard to integrate, which I'm thinking one that can be solved, again, by a contour integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the second summand is conjugate of the first:
$$
\frac1{\alpha-ix}=\overline{\frac1{\alpha+ix}}
$$
thus their sum will be real. In particular
$$
\frac1{\alpha+ix}+\frac1{\alpha-ix}=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+x^2}{}
$$
thus the integrand will be
$$
\frac{4\alpha^2}{(\alpha^2+x^2)^2}=\frac{4}{\alpha^2}\frac{1}{(1+(x/\alpha)^2)^2}
$$
The substitution $x=\alpha\tan y$ leads to (suppose wlog $\alpha>0$)
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac1{\alpha+ix}+\frac1{\alpha-ix}\right)^2\,dx
&=\frac{4}{\alpha^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+(x/\alpha)^2)^2}\\
&=\frac{4}{\alpha^2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+\tan^2y)^2}\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2y}\,dy\\
&=\frac{4}{\alpha}\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos^4y}}\frac{1}{\cos^2y}\,dy\\
&=\frac{4}{\alpha}\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}{\cos^2y}\,dy\\
&=\frac{4}{\alpha}\frac12\left[\cos y\sin y +y\right]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}
\end{align*}

Comment: I have done the part where you'll combine the fractions to form $\frac{4 \alpha^2}{(\alpha^2 + x^2)^2}$ but I have not thought of factoring out $\alpha^2$ from the denominator. I will try that out thanks!

Comment: I'm beginning to see that this can be done using $x = \alpha \tan \theta$ but I keep on getting extremely weird answers.

Comment: Nothing weird Aldon! I completed the answer. I hope it could be clearer now! :-)

Comment: I realized a few hours ago that I had wrong bounds for my integral when I converted it through $x = \alpha \tan \theta$. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 8):

The integral is even in $\alpha$, so assume that $\alpha\gt0$.

**Real Analysis Approach**

Substitute $x\mapsto\alpha x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{\alpha+ix}+\frac1{\alpha-ix}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+x^2}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac4\alpha\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(1+x^2)^2}\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore
$$
\begin{align}
\pi
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac2{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: arctan integral
$(3)$: integration by parts on $(2)$
$(4)$: multiply the integrand in $(2)$ by $\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2}$
$(5)$: $2$ times $(4)$ minus $(3)$

Plug $(5)$ into $(1)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{\alpha+ix}+\frac1{\alpha-ix}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac4\alpha\frac\pi2\\[3pt]
&=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Complex Analysis Approach**

Let $z=ix$ and $\gamma=[-iR,iR]\cup iRe^{i[0,\pi]}$ as $R\to\infty$.

[image]

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac1{\alpha+ix}+\frac1{\alpha-ix}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x
&=-i\int_\gamma\left(\frac1{\alpha+z}+\frac1{\alpha-z}\right)^2\mathrm{d}z\tag{7}\\
&=-i\int_\gamma\left(\frac1{(\alpha+z)^2}+\frac1{(\alpha-z)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}z\\
&-\frac i\alpha\int_\gamma\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac1{\alpha+z}}+\frac1{\alpha-z}\right)\mathrm{d}z\tag{8}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(7)$: the integral along the arc where $|z|=R$ is $\lesssim\frac{4\pi}R$, which vanishes as $R\to\infty$.
$(8)$: $\left(\frac1{\alpha+z}+\frac1{\alpha-z}\right)^2 =\frac1{(\alpha+z)^2}+\frac1{(\alpha-z)^2}+\frac2{(\alpha+z)(\alpha-z)} =\frac1{(\alpha+z)^2}+\frac1{(\alpha-z)^2}+\frac1\alpha\left(\frac1{\alpha+z}+\frac1{\alpha-z}\right)$
$(9)$: only the $\color{#C00000}{\frac1{\alpha+z}}$ term has a pole with non-zero residue inside $\gamma$

Comment: Why is $\left(\frac{1}{\alpha +z} + \frac{1}{\alpha - z}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{(\alpha + z)^2} + \frac{1}{(\alpha - z)^2}$?

Comment: you could also use the Fourier transform (harmonic analysis) approach.

if $\alpha < 0$ : $$\frac{1}{\alpha+ix} + \frac{1}{\alpha-ix} = 2 \pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2 i \pi x t} e^{2 \pi \alpha |t|} dt$$ so by the Parseval identity : $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left| \frac{1}{\alpha+ix} + \frac{1}{\alpha-ix} \right |^2 dx  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  |2 \pi e^{2 \pi \alpha |t|}|^2 dt = 4 \pi^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{4 \pi \alpha |t|} dt = 2\frac{4 \pi^2 }{4 \pi |\alpha|} = \frac{2 \pi }{|\alpha|}$$

Comment: and if $\alpha >  0$ : $\frac{1}{\alpha+ix} + \frac{1}{\alpha-ix} = - \left(\frac{1}{-\alpha-ix} + \frac{1}{-\alpha+ix} \right)$ so the result is still $\frac{2 \pi }{|\alpha|}$

Comment: @user1952009: indeed, there are many ways to compute the integral.

Comment: @Aldon: you missed the next line, which is a continuation.

Comment: @Aldon: I have expanded the explanation of the Complex Analysis Approach. Note the explanation of $(8)$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =4 \alpha^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\alpha^2+x^2\right)^2} d x \\
& =-2 \alpha^2 \int_{-\alpha}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} d\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2+x^2}\right) \\
& =2 \alpha^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha^2+x^2}\right) d x \\
& =2\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2+x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) d x\right. \\
& =2\left[\frac{1}{\alpha} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)+\frac{1}{x}\right]^{\infty}\\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\alpha}
\end{aligned}
$$